# Undefined variable msg in shoppingcart

Tags: php

Problem of undefined variable msg in shoppingcart.php

I am getting this error Notice: Undefined variable: msg in D:\wamp\www\project\shoppingcart\shoppingcart.php on line 64 . 
msg variable declare in code. but why it is giving a error !

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIUhq.png)

```
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");

//if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
}
```

2) msg variable used here

```
<div style="color:#F00"><?php echo $msg ?></div>
```

3) Error of cart variable as well undefined

```
<?php

        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
            echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                if($q==0) continue;
        ?>
```

Comment: `if(isset($_REQUEST["command"])=="update")` returns `false` because the `isset()` function can only return `true` or `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$msg` is not defined anywhere initially. Use `$msg = '';` to define the variable just after you include the files so that its always available.

```
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");

$msg = ''; // <-- Define here

//if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, same with case of cart variable, it is also undefined ?  Notice: Undefined index: cart in

Comment: Your current code does not show `$cart` anywhere. Though you can use the same solution and define it as blank before using or over-writing it.

Comment: chagne `if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){` to `if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){`

Comment: thanks i did! in this case, it gives me message of 
There are no items in your shopping cart! , although i have added quantity for placing an order

Comment: This means that the items are not added in the cart. check this by printing `$_SESSION` using `print_r($_SESSION);`. if it does not have `cart` offset, then it means that the cart is not set into the session

Comment: i have done Array print_r , it is giving me below results! 

    [cart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productid] => 1
                    [qty] => 1

Comment: Are you sure the same code you posted is giving such error? maybe some other line is causing this issue. You have to debug more on this as you have complete code with you.

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/scjqva7h5v86tpp/shoppingcart.rar?dl=0) Download the code

Comment: You need to understand this. This is a helping website not a freelance website. Nobody will download the code and will debug for you. You need to debug and tell where you are stuck.

Comment: Also this question should be closed by choosing a answer now. The latest question you are asking is not a part of the original question. We cant just keep on adding questions to the original question. All the answers here explains why the earlier issue came. learn it and apply to the next problem as well as its of similar nature.

Comment: i can understand! cart showing empty , after i checked print_r SESSION . thanks for your kind reply!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<div style="color:#F00"><?php echo isset($msg) ? $msg : '' ; ?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

This notice is coming because `$msg` is not defined anywhere. Use the following code.

```
include("includes/db.php");
include("includes/functions.php");

// Declare $msg here
$msg = '';

//if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
    remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
else if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'){
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
            $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        }
        else{
            $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use $msg whether it exists or not, that's where the error comes from. Try this:
   `<div style="color:#F00"><?php if(isset($msg)){ echo $msg; } ?></div>`